# Changing the rotated form of an Ellipse to y= form

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, analytic-geometry

So for a Algebra 2 project I'm supposed to create a figure with functions and circles. I want to recreate a face with ellipses acting as the eyes. The character I'm trying to recreate, Butters from South Park, has eyes that are ellipses but are rotated slightly.  I have the 2 equations for each of the eyes:
$$\frac{\left(\left(x-2.5\right)\cos\left(2\right)+\left(y\right)\sin\left(2\right)\right)^2}{\left(17\right)}+\frac{\left(\left(x+1.24328907\right)\sin\left(2\right)-\left(y\right)\cos\left(2\right)\right)^2}{\left(9\right)}=1$$

$$\frac{\left(\left(x+12\right)\cos\left(-2\right)+\left(y-1\right)\sin\left(-2\right)\right)^2}{\left(17\right)}+\frac{\left(\left(x+6\right)\sin\left(-2\right)-\left(y-1\right)\cos\left(-2\right)\right)^2}{\left(9\right)}=1$$

Part of the instructions is to the equations into y= format. For a normal ellipse you can use the equation in y= as:
$$y=b\sqrt{1-\frac{x-h}a}+k$$
so what would the equation of a rotated ellipse be in the rotated from involving sin and cos?
Thanks

Comment: If you expand to the form $ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f=0$ with $c\neq 0$ then $y=-\frac{bx+e}{2c}\pm\sqrt{(\frac{bx+e}{2c})^2-\frac{ax^2+dx+f}{c}}$.

Comment: Can you help me put my equations into standard form?

Comment: Using $2^\circ$, $$0.1110474261505836y^2-0.003647397319954264xy-0.01989468955879503y+0.05888721437229218x^2-0.293422909190631x-0.632591536474324=0$$ and $$0.1110474261505836y^2+0.003647397319954264xy-0.224830400291133y+0.05888721437229218x^2+1.408021781121608x+7.578926145309568=0$$ or $$0.01642270085129341x+0.08957744563938488\pm\sqrt{(-0.5300191670804171x^2)+2.645262874687893x+5.704613030395997}$$ and $$-0.01642270085129341x+1.01231702563847\pm\sqrt{(-0.5300191670804171x^2)-12.71271340961598x-67.22466772114753}$$

Comment: I'm having trouble inputting these onto Demsos so I can visualize them. Help

Comment: I use geogebra: `ImplicitCurve(((x-2.5)cos(2)+y sin(2))^2/17+((x+1.24328907)sin(2)-y cos(2))^2/9-1)` `ImplicitCurve(((x+12)cos(-2)+(y-1) sin(-2))^2/17+((x+6)sin(-2)-(y-1) cos(-2))^2/9-1)` `-sqrt((-0.5300191670804171*x^2)-12.71271340961598*x-67.22466772114753)  -0.01642270085129341*x+1.01231702563847` `sqrt((-0.5300191670804171*x^2)-12.71271340961598*x-67.22466772114753)  -0.01642270085129341*x+1.01231702563847` `-sqrt((-0.5300191670804171*x^2)+2.645262874687893*x+5.704613030395997)  +0.01642270085129341*x+0.08957744563938488`.

Comment: yes that works but it isn't in the y= form I'm looking for.  Can you please give me the equation in y= form.

Comment: Just put `y=-sqrt((-0.5300191670804171*x^2)+2.645262874687893*x+5.704613030395997)  +0.01642270085129341*x+0.08957744563938488` etc.